unexpected behaviour of flowrow in jetpackcompose
I have a screen in which users can see recommendations saved by them from different categories with filter buttons above implemented with the help of FlowRow:
@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
fun SavedScreen(
    savedRecommendationsMap: Map<Pair<CATEGORY, Boolean>, List<Recommendation>?>,
    onClick: (Recommendation, CATEGORY) -> Unit,
    onFilterButtonClick: (category: CATEGORY, isSelected: Boolean) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Rebugger(
        trackMap = mapOf(
            "savedRecommendationsMap" to savedRecommendationsMap,
            "onClick" to onClick,
            "onFilterButtonClick" to onFilterButtonClick,
            "modifier" to modifier,
        ),
    )
    
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium))
            .fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        FlowRow(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_small)),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {
            savedRecommendationsMap.forEach() { (key, value) ->
                Log.d(
                    "SavedScreen",
                    "Category: ${key.first}, isSelected: ${key.second}, recommendations: ${value?.size ?: 0}"
                )

                FilterButton(
                    onFilterButtonClick = onFilterButtonClick,
                    filterName = key.first,
                    isFilterSelected = key.second,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_small)),
                )
            }

        }
        
        HorizontalDivider(
            thickness = 2.dp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium)),
        )
        
        if (!savedRecommendationsMap.any { it.value != null }) {
            NothingScreen(modifier = modifier)
        } else {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
            ) {
                item {
                    savedRecommendationsMap.forEach { (key, value) ->
                        if (key.second == true) {
                            value?.forEach {
                                SavedScreenCard(
                                    recommendation = it,
                                    onClick = onClick,
                                    category = key.first,
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



On the left is the preview. It works fine, but when on a device (right) as you can see only 2 buttons are appearing. Moreover when I tried to find a fix it I came across another issue that this composable is getting recomposed four times. I used Rebugger and used logged to find the reason but I am still unable to fix it.
Logs:
Category: COFFEESHOPS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: RESTRAUNTS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: PARKS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: SHOPPINGCENTERS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: HOTELS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Rebugger recomposed because 
     `onClick` changed from `Function2<com.example.prguetravel.model.Recommendation, com.example.prguetravel.utils.CATEGORY, kotlin.Unit>` to `Function2<com.example.prguetravel.model.Recommendation, com.example.prguetravel.utils.CATEGORY, kotlin.Unit>`, 
     `onFilterButtonClick` changed from `Function2<com.example.prguetravel.utils.CATEGORY, java.lang.Boolean, kotlin.Unit>` to `Function2<com.example.prguetravel.utils.CATEGORY, java.lang.Boolean, kotlin.Unit>`, 
     `modifier` instance changed, but content remains the same -> `androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValuesElement@e5200000`
Category: COFFEESHOPS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: RESTRAUNTS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: PARKS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: SHOPPINGCENTERS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: HOTELS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
 Rebugger activated on `Rebugger`
Category: COFFEESHOPS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: RESTRAUNTS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: PARKS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: SHOPPINGCENTERS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: HOTELS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Rebugger recomposed because 
     `onClick` changed from `Function2<com.example.prguetravel.model.Recommendation, com.example.prguetravel.utils.CATEGORY, kotlin.Unit>` to `Function2<com.example.prguetravel.model.Recommendation, com.example.prguetravel.utils.CATEGORY, kotlin.Unit>`, 
     `onFilterButtonClick` changed from `Function2<com.example.prguetravel.utils.CATEGORY, java.lang.Boolean, kotlin.Unit>` to `Function2<com.example.prguetravel.utils.CATEGORY, java.lang.Boolean, kotlin.Unit>`, 
     `modifier` instance changed, but content remains the same -> `androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValuesElement@e5200000`
Category: COFFEESHOPS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: RESTRAUNTS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: PARKS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: SHOPPINGCENTERS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: HOTELS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: COFFEESHOPS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: RESTRAUNTS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: PARKS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: SHOPPINGCENTERS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0
Category: HOTELS, isSelected: true, recommendations: 0


could it simply be that you are accidentally drawing behind the toolbar? Maybe try adding some top padding to the outer column or the FlowRow itself, to see if that's the case. If you are using Scaffold, this might happen when you do not consume the insets provided to the content lambda

@AdrianK you're life saver mate i was struggling to find the solution tried dozens of things first of all thanks the issue did fixed but didn't why there's so much recomposition

The FlowRow seems incomplete because the SavedScreen Composable is being hidden behind the TopAppBar. You are probably using a Scaffold at some point. Make sure that you are applying the padding that the Scaffold provides to the content:
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        //...
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            //...
        }
    }
)

Before we can look into any recomposition analysis: You are iteratively adding new elements to a single LazyColumn item by using forEach. This will this make the LazyColumn itself pointless, as it will always contain only one single item.
I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but if you want to show each SavedScreenCard as a single item in the LazyColumn, please consider to update your code as follows:
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
) {
    savedRecommendationsMap.forEach { (key, value) ->
        if (key.second == true) {
            value?.forEach { recommendation ->
                item {
                    SavedScreenCard(
                        recommendation = recommendation,
                        onClick = onClick,
                        category = key.first,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This will result in a proper LazyColumn usage, where only the items that are currently visible (and a few more) are composed, and the other items are lazily composed when scrolling.

that wrapping it inside a item was temporary fix because i was getting an error composable invocation can be done from only composable function so i thought i'll check it later
